# Get the URL response code before ViewController loads?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to get the status *code* of the `URL` before the `MainViewController` loads, now I know walk arounds but is it doable? I tried putting the *code* in `willEnterForeground`, `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and on `init()`, with the last one working from time to time. 
Before anyone asks or thinks as to why I might do this, I am mostly wondering now, is there a faster way to get the response *code* etc.

```
 let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { _, response, _ in
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 404 {

               print("404")

            } else  if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {

                print("200")

            }  
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use a loading status. or else do this on main thread

Comment: You cannot get the response code before loading the whole requests. To load the whole request before showing the view you will have to use the really bad practice of loading the site on a blocking thread.

Comment: You're right, although this settles what i was wondering, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create a new view controller that will indicate that somethings is loading, then push/present the `MainViewController` on the success of the asynchronous method.

If you try to block the main thread until the status comes, the iOS watchdog will likely kill of your app. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1592/_index.html)